# How do you use if (IsPostBack) in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, ispostback

How can I used `if (IsPostBack){}` to display user's names from two text boxes into another text box?

I have 3 text boxes and a button. The text boxes are named txtLastName, txtGivenName, txtOutput. My button is btnSubmit.

How can I display text from the txtLastName and txtGivenName in the txtOutput text box?

How can I display it as: First (space) Lastname or Last, Firstname in this code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure what you're asking. `IsPostback` isn't really meant for this. You're better off using the `btnSubmit_Click` event

Comment: I just noticed that you donot consider casting votes. It will cost nothing to you but will encourage others more to help you.]

Comment: What do you mean by casting votes Pankaj?

Comment: you should consider upvoting good answers.

Comment: Oh yeah, I always do that, was late recently due to sickness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I display text from the txtLastName and txtGivenName in the
>   txtOutput text box?

1. Go to the design of your page.
2. Click the button.
3. Click F4 or Right click and select properties. This will show you a window for button.
4. Click the event.
5. Double click the "Click" action.
6. This will navigate you to the code behind.
7. Write the code in this handler
8. This is how the design will look like for your event handler

[image]

---

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtOutput.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", txtGivenName.Text, txtLastName.Text);
}
```

---

> How can I display it as: First (space) Lastname or Last, Firstname in
>   this code.

Write down the code in the handler as below.

```
txtOutput.Text = txtLast.Text + ", " + txtFirst.Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an event handler for the Click event on the button and then in the code behind, do like this:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtOutput.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", txtGivenName.Text, txtLastName.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
        txtOutput.Text = txtLastName.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use use the submit button method to achieve this?

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    txtOutput.Text = txtLast.Text + ", " + txtFirst.Text;
}
```

Comment: Access modifier and return type is missing.